# Calling a Function in JavaScript to Return HTML

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a function **checkLength** to test whether a user-entered number is 16 digits long.  If it is 16 digits, I would like to continue my function **main**; otherwise I want to output an error message *"Please enter a 16-digit number"*.  My code is below:

```js
function main() {
    "use strict";
    // set variable for user-entered number
    var userNum = document.getElementById("userNum"),
        // use that variable to initialize array
        array = [userNum.value],
        // convert array to string
        values = array.toString();
    
    // call function "checkLength" with parameter "values"
    checkLength(values);
    
    // more code below that is excluded for simplification 
}

function checkLength(x) {
    "use strict";
    if (x.length !== 16) {
        return document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Please enter a 16-digit number.";
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that every-time it executes, I get the output *"Please enter a 16-digit number."*, even when I enter a 16 digit number.

I have tried debugging this for several hours and just can't determine where I'm going wrong.  I'm not necessarily looking for a solution, but just a general direction of where I should be looking (improper scope, return statements, etc.).  I greatly appreciate your assistance!

Comment: You are checking length of array. Please post your full code and html. Or call your `checkLength(userNum.value);` by passing `userNum value`.

Comment: May I ask the purpose of `array = [userNum.value]` and `values = array.toString()`? Would `userNum.value.length` not work?

Comment: There is a *Run code snippet* button in your question, but it is useless because you didn't bother to (a) include any HTML or (b) call either of your functions. You should provide a **complete** [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Here I can see that once the output is set when entering the digit which is not 16 digits long and it persists in the DOM.

I assume that main() is called on any event of the textbox or any button.

The solution is you need to reset the "output" element if the input is 16 digits long.

Please change your checkLength function as given below,

```
function checkLength(x) {
    "use strict";
    if (x.length !== 16) {
         return document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Please enter a 16-digit number.";
    }
    else {
        //Added below line of code.
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="";
        return false;
    }
}
```

=====================================

Another improvement should be- use "length" property of text.

Use length property get the length of a value of textbox as given below,

```
function main() {
    "use strict";
    // set variable for user-entered number
    var userNum = document.getElementById("userNum");

    //variable to hold length of input box    
     inputLength = userNum.value.length;

    // call function "checkLength" with parameter "values"
    checkLength(inputLength);

    // more code below that is excluded for simplification 
}
```

Comment: This reads like a game of spot-the-difference rather than an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem?

Comment: @Quentin, Can you please let me know what are the improvements required or what to change to improve. I will take care of it.

Comment: @Quentin I believe this could be the problem, actually if the main function is executed in the start of the page, the page will show "Please enter a 16-digit number.", if the user enters a new value of 16 digit it will show the same because the HTML never changed.

Answer (score 0):

As in other answer by [@Parth Lukhi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53154065/9695286) you have to rest html on `checkLength` and also you have to put condition like `if(!checkLength(values))` then it should `return` and not execute further.

```js
function main() {
    "use strict";
    // set variable for user-entered number
    var userNum = document.getElementById("userNum"),
        // use that variable to initialize array
        array = [userNum.value],
        // convert array to string
        values = array.toString();
    
    // call function "checkLength" with parameter "values"
    if(!checkLength(values)) 
        return;
    
    // more code below that is excluded for simplification 
}

function checkLength(x) {
    "use strict";
    if (x.length !== 16) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Please enter a 16-digit number.";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function main() {
    "use strict";
    var a = document.getElementById("userNum").value;
    checkLength(a); 
}
function checkLength(x) {
    "use strict";
    if (x.length != 16) {
        return document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Please enter a 16-digit number.";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = " entered value is 16 digit";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userNum" value="Mickey are you ?">
<button onclick="main()">click me</button><div id="output"></div>
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explain what you added or changed, and why.

Comment: Sure @PeterB will do that

Answer (score 0):

it is because your `checkLength()` return only `false` and no html message written

```js
function main() {
  "use strict";
  // set variable for user-entered number
  var userNum = document.getElementById("userNum"),
    // use that variable to initialize array
    array = [userNum.value],
    // convert array to string
    values = array.toString();

  // call function "checkLength" with parameter "values"
  checkLength(values);

  // more code below that is excluded for simplification 
}

function checkLength(x) {
  "use strict";
  var message, isValid = false;
  if (x.length !== 16) {
    message = "Please enter a 16-digit number. (" + x.length + ")";
  } else {
    isValid = true;
    message = "Correct: " + x;
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = message;
  return isValid;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="userNum" oninput="main()">
<p id="output">
  0
</p>
```